# While loop isn't working correctly?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am creating a maths quiz for practice in python programming and I have encountered a problem. I am attempting to create a `while` loop to use it as verification to make sure that the user has either entered 1, 2 or, 3. When I use this loop it just continues the loop and doesn't exit.

```
cl = int(input("Please enter your class (1, 2 or, 3): "))  

while cl != 1 or cl != 2 or cl != 3 : 
    cl = int(input("Please enter your class (1, 2 or, 3): "))
```

I have code after to save other information to a text file (I know csv files may be easier), and it wont continue to this code.

How can I fix this or is there a better way of doing what I am attempting? `cl` is a variable that will be the user's input in the form of an integer. The integer will be used to select between if and elif statements.

Comment: It’d be more obvious written as `while cl not in [1, 2, 3]:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This condition is always True! To make it work you need to use an `and` instead:

```
while cl != 1 and cl != 2 and cl != 3: 
              ^^^         ^^^
```

Take the basic case: `c1 != 1 or c1 != 2` and see how the logic applies to both your `while` condition and the one I suggest:

```
c1       c1 != 1   c1 != 2   (c1 != 1 or c1 != 2) (c1 != 1 and c1 != 2)
1         false     true             true                  false
2         true      false            true                  false
!1,2      true      true             true                  true
```